# Getting error when pasing an array as an argument to Event

Tags: php, laravel, event-listener

I get the following error when I am passing an array as an argument to the `TeamMemberUpdating` event:

> Argument 1 passed to App\Events\Event ::__construct() must be an instance of App\Models\Model, instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection given

Here is where I fire the event:

```
$teamMembers = TeamMember::whereIn('email', $request->projectTeamEmails)->get();
event(new TeamMemberUpdating($teamMembers));
```

My event:

```
class TeamMemberUpdating
{
use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;
public $teamMembers;
/**
 * Create a new event instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct(TeamMember $teamMembers)
{
    $this->teamMembers = $teamMembers;
}
}
```

And my listener `handle()` method:

```
public function handle(TeamMemberUpdating $event)

{   
    TeamMemberLog::insert($event->teamMembers);
}
```

Comment: Instead `public function __construct(TeamMember $teamMembers)` put `public function __construct(Collection $teamMembers)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your event class is defined to not handle arrays, the constructor is strictly hinting a single instance of `TeamMember`

```
public function __construct(TeamMember $teamMembers)
{
    $this->teamMembers = $teamMembers;
}
```

You can change it to:

```
public function __construct($teamMembers)
{
    $this->teamMembers = $teamMembers;
}
```

This way it would accept both a single `TeamMember` and a `Collection` of team members. You can do `instanceof` checks to determine what is passed in.

Alternatively you can change your dispatch methodology:

```
$teamMembers = TeamMember::whereIn('email', $request->projectTeamEmails)->get();
$teamMembers->each(function ($teamMember) {
    event(new TeamMemberUpdating($teamMember));
});
```

This will dispatch an event for each model instance

Comment: To avoid mess, listener handler should accept collection, event also, and when event is called, it should be something like `if (!($teamMembers instanceof  Collection)) {collect($teamMembers)}` which should be in some private method of controller I'd say. It's not good practice to allow to same constructor variable (like in Event class here) to accept different type.